# Em.View.create deprecation warnings

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a `CollectionView` which has `itemViewClass` set up to a template which has an action that opens a modal containing the same data, but displayed in a different way. The modal is generated as a view and is passed the content from `itemViewClass`, but upon `.append()` the `defaultContainer` deprecation warning comes up.

Without further ado, here is the [JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/luyat/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation for the deprecation warning you're seeing can be found in [this gist](http://git.io/EKPpnA).

Here is an [updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fapaxaqu/2) with (hopefully) the solution to your problem.

Passing in the `container` removes the deprecation warning, but this is not an idiomatic Ember code you would find in your neighbour's application. Usually you would use a transient route that would populate another outlet with your modal.

You expected bindings would work when you pass plain old JavaScript object to `Ember.View`, but that is not the case. Wrap that in the `Em.Object` and everything gets wired up.

Also, please be a bit more descriptive with your questions, it was a little tricky to find out what you were trying to accomplish here.